# How to print variable number of elements using sep and end?

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, for-loop, formatting

I've been trying to use the `sep=''` to separate the numbers in between each other but they never separate unless I use `end=""`.
However, when I switch `sep=''` with `end=""` it works properly.
So, what am I doing wrong?
Also, how do I separate the numbers in between with a `"+"` symbol without having it appear at the end?

Thanks!

```
#Counter
numcounter=0
#Get starting integer from user

s_num=int(input("Please enter a valid starting integer number: "))

#Get ending integer from user

e_num=int(input("Please enter a valid ending integer number: "))

#For loop

for numbers in range (s_num,e_num+1):
    numcounter+=numbers
    print(numbers, sep='')
```

This was the output:

```
Python 3.4.1 (v3.4.1:c0e311e010fc, May 18 2014, 10:38:22) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Please enter a valid starting integer number: 1
Please enter a valid ending integer number: 5
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Can you show a sample input and expected output?

Comment: Just edited it and posted the output!

Answer (score 1):

You can use string join function to join item in the list with some string, here is example

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
'+'.join( map(str,a))
<<< '1+2+3+4'
```

so your case should be

```
print( ' '.join(map(str,numbers)) )
```

Comment: I technically haven't "learned" that yet so I can't use it.
I know it can be done just by use sep= and end= but I don't know how to use them properly.

Comment: Doesn't work any way, gives `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found`. You need to convert the numbers to strings first, like `print( ' '.join(map(str, numbers) ) )`

Comment: Sorry, just missing to convert integer to string

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation for the [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=print#print)-function. It takes a variable numbers to print out separated by the given `sep` and ended with `end`. So you can simply use the `*syntax` to pass your sequence to `print`. Simply:

```
>>> print(*range(1,5))
1 2 3 4
>>> print(*range(1,5), sep='+')
1+2+3+4
>>> print(*range(1,5), sep='+', end='=' + str(sum(range(1,5))))
1+2+3+4=10
```

Answer (score -1):

You're using `numbers` in a for loop. Even though the variable name is plural, it only gets one value at a time.  i.e., if `s_num==1` and `e_num==2`, the for loop will be unfolded to the following:

```
numbers=1
print(1, sep='')
numbers=2
print(2, sep='')
```

As you see, `numbers` takes a single value from the range each time through the for loop, not the whole range. `sep` is used to separate multiple values being printed out from a variable list of arguments passed to the print function. Since there is only a single value being printed out in each print statement, there is nothing to separate so setting `sep` does nothing.