# how do i properly make a for loop sit on one line, with commas and no spaces

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, for-loop, number-formatting

I'm new to coding and it's a little frustrating at the moment because i have to do an assessment where it outputs "1,2,fizz,4,buzz,fizz,7,8,fizz,buzz,11,fizz,13,14,fizzbuzz,16,17,fizz,19,buzz" and no i cant use print.

Code:

```
import sys
num1=int(input('Enter your number range: '))
for x in range(1,num1+1):
   if x % 3 == 0:
      print("Fizz",end=" ")
   if x % 5 == 0:
      print('Buzz',end=" ")
   if x % 3 != 0 and x % 5 != 0:
      print(str(x),end=" ")
```

Result: "enter your number range?"(well say 20)

```
1 2 Fizz 4 Buzz Fizz 7 8 Fizz Buzz 11 Fizz 13 14 Fizz Buzz 16 17 Fizz 19 Buzz
```

so as you can see its on the same line but i don't want spaces, and i want commas in between each number and letter accept where number 15 should be, i want that to one word "FizzBuzz", as seen on the example :

```
1,2,fizz,4,buzz,fizz,7,8,fizz,buzz,11,fizz,13,14,fizzbuzz,16,17,fizz,19,buzz
```

Comment: You cannot use print? You mean that You cannot just print this string or You cannot use it anywhere in Your program?

Comment: OK, I think you're almost there. What does `end=" "` do in your `print` calls? What test can you do to see if you should be printing "FizzBuzz" as one word?

Comment: When i use end="", it pulls the line bellow it up so instead of displaying on different lines it brings it up to the same line

Comment: Right, so instead of each string you print ending with a newline (`\n`), it ends with a space. Can you see how to use that to get commas instead of spaces between your values?

Comment: i found one way but it futs a comma between every word and number, which is party what i want but i need number 15 to be the full word "FizzBuzz", also i still have spaces in-between my words and numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically the same question I have answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29667312/3635816). If you look at the documentation for [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), it says you print a variable number of objects (`*objects` in the docs). `print` takes a `sep` keyword, which is the character(s) you want to separate your printed objects with.

If you modify you code slightly to collect the items-to-be-printed in a list first and then print all at once:

```
num1=int(input('Enter your number range: '))
items = list()
for x in range(1,num1+1):
    if x % 3 == 0:
        items.append("Fizz")
    if x % 5 == 0:
        items.append('Buzz')
    if x % 3 != 0 and x % 5 != 0:
        items.append(str(x))

print(*items, sep=',')
```

When you run it:

```
Enter your number range: 10
1,2,Fizz,4,Buzz,Fizz,7,8,Fizz,Buzz
```

For the `*objects`-syntax you can take a look at this [SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3394835/3635816).

---

To account for numbers evenly divisible with both 3 and 5:

```
num1=int(input('Enter your number range: '))
items = list()
for x in range(1,num1+1):
    if x % 5 == 0 and x % 3 == 0:
        items.append('FizzBuzz')
    elif x % 3 == 0:
        items.append("Fizz")
    elif x % 5 == 0:
        items.append('Buzz')
    else:
        items.append(str(x))

print(*items, sep=',')
```

Comment: thank you, its very close now i just need to figure out how to get that pesky number 15 to be one word not two, because multiple of 3 are "Fizz" . With multiples of 5 are "Buzz".  If the number is a multiple of both 3 and 5 then its "FizzBuzz".

Comment: Thanks everyone for your contribution, now it;s working %100. can i just ask what (in line 3) "(1,num1+1)" the first 1 does to the code?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use print for formating, but simply join the different string elements.
Enter this in the interpreter:

```
','.join([     'FizzBuzz' if not(i%15) 
          else 'Fizz'     if not(i%3)
          else 'Buzz'     if not(i%5)
          else str(i)
          for i in range(1,a+1)
         ])
```

or put the above line inside a print statement